# How to get the string values from the NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, json, sdk, xcode4.2

After json parsing i get the dictionary values like this way

```
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

After printing the json dictionary i get the below output

```
{
       Title= "hi";
        title2 = "welcome";
        FriendlyName = B325;
        Id = 1;
        MyLocation = "opp";
        sliders =         (
                        {
                NAme1 = hai;
                Name2 = "apple";
                Name3 = "world";
                Name4 = "happiness";
            }
        );
        Address = "northZone";
        Title3 = "hello world";
    },
        {
       title= "hi";
        title2 = "welcome";
        FriendlyName = B325;
        Id = 2;
        MyLocation = "opp1";
        sliders =         (
                        {
                NAme1 = hai;
                Name2 = "apple";
                Name3 = "world";
                Name4 = "happiness";
            }
        );
        Address = "westZone";
        Title3 = "hello world";
    },

    title= "hi";
    title2 = "welcome";
    FriendlyName = B325;
    Id = 3;
    MyLocation = "opp";
    sliders =         (
                    {
            NAme1 = hai;
            Name2 = "apple";
            Name3 = "world";
            Name4 = "happiness";
        }
    );
    Address = "southZone";
    Title3 = "hello world";
},
 '''''''''etc.,


NSMutableArray *resultArray = [json objectForKey:@"title"];
```

i want to  store the dictionary strings into  resultarray  but execution has stopped in the above step

How will i store the dictionary values into an array?

please help me

Comment: Did you tried [Object allValues] method for NSDictionary object?

Comment: @Mehdzor yes i tried but no use And also my full code is NSDictionary *resultsDict = [json valueForKey:  @"Title1"];   NSDictionary *selector = [json valueForKey: @"sliders"]; 
    NSLog(@"333333333%@",selector);
 NSMutableArray *dictArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: selector,nil];
    
    NSLog(@"dictarray%@",dictArray);
  
for(int i = 0; i<[dictArray count]; i++)
    {
       NSString * str1=[[dictArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name2"];
        NSLog(@"the stringone is %@",str1);} but all values store in a single string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output you show, it looks like your JSON object is already an array of dictionaries.  However, your statement/question does not make sense to me, so I can't figure out what you really want.

There are more fancy ways to access your data, but this should give you a basic idea and hopefully get you on your way...

```
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // Your top-object is an array of objects.  It can hold strings, numbers,
    // arrays, dictionaries (and NSNull).
} else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // your top level object is a dictionary
}
```

From here, you should be able to verify what you have.  I bet you are getting an array of dictionaries.  At that point, just iterate over the top level array and query each dictionary for its contents.

Answer (score 0):

try use this code

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[resultArray addObject:[json objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

Comment: i initialise my array in viewdidload.